# Video sync generator IC

Tags: microcontroller, video, synchronization

I have a board which is a PAL CCIR video sync generator card having [SAA1043](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet_pdf/philips/SAA1043.pdf). The IC is accepting external sync signal from pin 15 and generating composite pulse on pin 26 and burst output on pin 1.

This IC is now obsolete and I am planning to replace this card. While searching for sync generator ICs, I mostly find sync separator for example MAX9568.

My questions are:

1. What is difference between sync generator and separator?  Can I use MAX9568 circuit in place of SAA1043 circuit?  Would that work?
2. Can I replace this card with a Microcontroller based sync generator card?  Is this doable?  If yes, any article for guidance because I am really confused what exactly sync generation is?

Edit: Schematics attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> What is difference between sync generator and separator?

Big difference. The generator creates all the extra pulse information while the separator strips off the extra information to extract only the H sync pulses.

> Can I use MAX9568 circuit in place of SAA1043 circuit? Would that work?

NO

========================================================

The SAA1032 Sync Gen is mainly for the VCR standard input & Sync while the  MAX9568 Sync Separator is only for Composite Video input. (Yellow phono plug)

Consumer VCR IC technology is getting or is already obsolete.   So keep looking.

These are common output signals.

[image]

> Can I replace this card with a Microcontroller based sync generator card? Is this doable?

Maybe

First you must *master* your understanding of how it works.

Comment: Agreed. But I want the replacement either based on newer IC or MCU designed. MAX9568 also generate a composite sync output on pin 1. Is it possible to use this IC to replace SAA1043? Same questions again.

Comment: NO wrong IC , nothing in common on the input..

Comment: I have attached the circuit implemented on board, in question. Any help please?

Comment: We are over two decades into the high definition television era.  I'd be surprised if *any* of the old composite video parts still are available.  I have a couple, but they are for NTSC (US).

Comment: @AnalogKid has never worked with the schlocker disti market. There will be stock for many more decades for (1of) but are pricey these days. https://www.digipart.com/part/SAA1043

Comment: Once again, I forgot to check the age of the thread before replying.  OTOH, I'm impressed that you know the things I've never done.  Have we met?

Comment: Not yet.  but if you worked in that market as I did for 1 yr with some guys in Long island. You would never have said that. We can facetime anytime you like. I also did 2 summers working in Earth Sciences with a seismic auto-recorder design and field tests

Comment: When I designed a headmounted video NTSC to AMLCD display , I did the sync timer in Xylinx. I  dont' think PAL and NTSC is dead yet like VCR's and capture cards and video cards still generate RGB on VGA . So this threat is for future seekers in analog low BW